# pandas csv reader produces wrong result

Tags: pandas

I have a python script that produces a wrong date format.

```
import csv
import urllib
import requests
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import io

link = 'https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19.csv'
s = requests.get(link).content
coviddata = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')),
                        parse_dates=['date'],
                        index_col= ['date'],
                        na_values=['999.99'])
prinput = 'Quebec'
ispr = coviddata['prname'] == prinput
covidpr = coviddata[ispr]
print(covidpr)
```

The data it produces seems to garble up dates as shown below.

```
        pruid  prname prnameFR  ...  numtotal  numtoday  numtested
```

date                                ...
**2020-01-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         1         1        NaN
2020-03-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         1         0        NaN
2020-05-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         2         1        NaN
2020-06-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         2         0        NaN
2020-07-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         2         0        NaN
2020-08-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         3         1        NaN
2020-09-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         4         1        NaN
2020-11-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...         7         3        NaN
2020-12-03     24  Quebec   Québec  ...        13         6        NaN**
2020-03-13     24  Quebec   Québec  ...        17         4        NaN
2020-03-14     24  Quebec   Québec  ...        17         0        NaN

Now on the contrary
here is another code snippet which works.

```
import csv
import urllib
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime
link = 'https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19.csv'

text = requests.get(link).text
lines = text.splitlines()
infile = csv.DictReader(lines)
prinput = input("Enter province(EN):")
xvalues=[]
yvalues=[]
for row in infile:
    if(row['prname']==prinput):
    xvalues.append(row['date'])
    yvalues.append(row['numconf'])
    print(row['prname'],row['date'],row['numconf'])
```

It produces the right dates
**Quebec 01-03-2020 1
Quebec 03-03-2020 1
Quebec 05-03-2020 2
Quebec 06-03-2020 2
Quebec 07-03-2020 2
Quebec 08-03-2020 3
Quebec 09-03-2020 4
Quebec 11-03-2020 7
Quebec 12-03-2020 13**
Quebec 13-03-2020 17
Quebec 14-03-2020 17
Quebec 15-03-2020 24
Quebec 16-03-2020 39
Quebec 17-03-2020 50

What is wrong with the first script?

Comment: When you say 'garble up the dates', do you mean changes the date format to YYYY-MM-DD instead of DD-MM-YYYY as used in the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Because you've used the `parse_dates` attribute, pandas interprets the 'date' column as a date-time object. This can be very useful for plotting data over time, or resampling your data over given time periods. If you want to restructure the datetime format for printing of your dataset, you can use `dt.strftime` attribute of the datetime series to do so.
i.e

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Read in dataframe from url
covid_df = pd.read_csv("https://health-infobase.canada.ca/src/data/covidLive/covid19.csv", 
                       parse_dates=['date'], na_values=[999.99])

# Create new column date-str that's the string interpretation of the 'date' column
covid_df['date-str'] = covid_df['date'].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

# Show the top of the dataframe
covid_df.head()
"""
   pruid            prname              prnameFR       date  ...  numtotal  numtoday  numtested    date-str
0     35           Ontario               Ontario 2020-01-31  ...         3         3        NaN  31-01-2020
1     59  British Columbia  Colombie-Britannique 2020-01-31  ...         1         1        NaN  31-01-2020
2      1            Canada                Canada 2020-01-31  ...         4         4        NaN  31-01-2020
3     35           Ontario               Ontario 2020-08-02  ...         3         0        NaN  02-08-2020
4     59  British Columbia  Colombie-Britannique 2020-08-02  ...         4         3        NaN  02-08-2020
"""

# Show dtypes and properties of each column of the dataframe
covid_df.info()
"""
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 302 entries, 0 to 301
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   pruid      302 non-null    int64         
 1   prname     302 non-null    object        
 2   prnameFR   302 non-null    object        
 3   date       302 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 4   numconf    302 non-null    int64         
 5   numprob    302 non-null    int64         
 6   numdeaths  302 non-null    int64         
 7   numtotal   302 non-null    int64         
 8   numtoday   302 non-null    int64         
 9   numtested  0 non-null      float64       
 10  date-str   302 non-null    object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(6), object(3)
memory usage: 26.1+ KB
"""
```